# Postgresql sending the query result very slowly via network

Tags: performance, postgresql, networking, psql

I have spent few days on fixing the slow sql query running without success. I have found a lot similar question and answer, but I have a different problem:

-I have a simple table with arround 5000 record and 30 columns
-I sent a simple `select * from this_table` command via pgAdmin3 and working for 15-20 sec for display the results

No `JOIN`and no `WHERE`.

I realized, when the query is running the postgresql send data to the client via LAN only 4 Mb/ps. I have gigabit LAN. The file copy, ftp and anything else is running on 700-800 Mb/ps on same channel on this server.

I already tested same sql command on the server console with psql command. The query is finished only few ms, this is ok. I don't have disk and any file problem.

I have read all documentation about postgresql config, increased the `work_mem` and so on, without any success.

What can I do?

Comment: you read all all documentation?

Comment: try `\copy` on client side with `psql` - maybe displaying data takes long, not transferring?..

Answer (score 0):

The time is almost certainly spent in pgAdmin III, check the process' CPU utilisation to be certain. It can take pgAdmin III a long time to display a large result set.

Maybe you should use `psql` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The CPU is running on 5-10%. I see the network process on the Mikrotik router. I see exactly, the data moving from the server to the client on 4mbps (slowly). As I wrote, on the server and the result is displayed in few ms.

Comment: How is the performance if you use `psql` on the client machine?

Comment: ops! the psql from the client is readed on 431 Mbps... (100x faster...) Now, I realized, the pgAdmin is realy slow, and I have to check the devart dotConnect component for speed up my windows app software. Now, I'm sure, the server side, network and etc is ok. Maybe i will try odbc connection. Thnx for your comment!

Comment: Yes, using pgAdmin III from inside an application is almost certainly not the right thing. If you plan to use .NET, why use an ODBC connection? Use the native interface for the programming language you are using.

Comment: Im using DevartDot Connect component (not a free component) in my .NET applications. Now, I will check my code and possibilities for speed up.